# Change the sorting order used for Book nodes

Tags: 6, hooks, nodes

How can I change the order used for Book nodes, which by default is based on weight and title?

I have a set of nodes displayed inside a page that use a structured book. I want to display them ordered by weight and random, instead of weight and name.

The book is used to structure different types of local companies and restaurants.

I have traced the code looking for a solution, but it's a bit messy for me.

Is there a hook that could be helpful to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout the [Book helper](http://drupal.org/project/book_helper) module.

> The Book helper module enables additional features from Drupal's menu system to improve the ordering of a book's pages. This module also allows administrators to further customize a book's navigation block.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Enhances the book outline manager
> - Adds 'enable' checkbox (aka hidden) to the manage book outline page
> - Adds an 'Order' tab (node/%/order) to a book's main page
> - Adds 'administer own book outlines' permission for ordering books from a book's main page
> - Removes the 'Outline' tab from all nodes
> - Removes the book fieldset from node edit pages if the content type does not allowed book outlines
> - Removes 'add child page' and 'printer-friendly version'
> - Removes book navigation
> - Customizes visibility of a book's navigation elements
> - Automatically 'Create new book' for selected content types
> - Includes 'Book (inline) navigation' block that can be easily positioned after a node's content
> - Disables new revisions from being created when a book's node title is updated
> - Displays a warning when deleting a book page (node/%/delete) that has child pages